# PayPalRESTException: Error code : 500

Tags: java, paypal

I am using the PayPal sandbox to make test payments. It had been working fine since last yesterday, I am getting Error 500 continuously since yesterday,

I checked link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR,
It didn't help much to find the reason behind the issue.

Java Stack-trace:

> com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 500 with response : {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"e1242b0ed621b"}
>       at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException.createFromHttpErrorException(PayPalRESTException.java:66)
>       at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:436)
>       at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:266)
>       at com.paypal.api.payments.CreditCard.create(CreditCard.java:368)
>       at com.elegantra.service.impl.PaypalRestServiceImpl.createCreditCard(PaypalRestServiceImpl.java:130)
>       at com.elegantra.service.impl.PaymentServiceImpl.newCardPayment(PaymentServiceImpl.java:191)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.newCardPayment(Unknown Source)
>       at com.elegantra.service.impl.PaymentServiceImplTest.testSuccessfulPaymentWithNewCard(PaymentServiceImplTest.java:154)
>       at com.elegantra.service.impl.PaymentServiceImplTest.testSuccessfulPaymentAmountLessThan1000(PaymentServiceImplTest.java:248)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: com.paypal.base.exception.HttpErrorException: Error code : 500 with response : {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"e1242b0ed621b"}
>       at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:173)
>       at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:71)
>       at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:424)
>       ... 49 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Response Code : 500 change log level to DEBUG for details.
>       at com.paypal.base.HttpConnection.executeWithStream(HttpConnection.java:153)
>       ... 51 more

Here is the test that used to run but now its failing :

```
@Test
public void testSuccessfulPaymentWithNewCard() throws Exception {
    NewCardPaymentDto paymentDto = new NewCardPaymentDto();

    paymentDto.setCardType("visa");
    paymentDto.setCardNumber("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    paymentDto.setExpYear("YYYY");
    paymentDto.setExpMonth("MM");
    paymentDto.setCvv("000");
    paymentDto.setZipcode("94085");
    paymentDto.setConsumerId(user.getUserId());
    paymentDto.setOrderId(orderDetails.getId());
    paymentDto.setTip(1.0);
    paymentDto.setNameOnCard("John Doe");

    //making call to paypal service 
    PaymentStatus paymentStatus = paymentService.newCardPayment(newCard,
            orderDetails);

    Card card = cardRepository.findByLastFourDigits("5105");


    assertThat(paymentStatus.getId(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(paymentStatus.getStatus(), equalTo("approved"));
    assertThat(paymentStatus.getCard(), equalTo(card));
}
```

PaymentServiceImpl.newCardPayment is making call to paypal rest api, snippet:

```
Payment payment = paypalRestService.makeDirectPayment(orderDetails.computeAmount(), newCard.getCardType(), 
                    newCard.getCardNumber(), newCard.getExpMonth(), newCard.getExpYear(), newCard.getCvv(), newCard.getNameOnCard());
```

Below are the details I got from paypal sandbox transaction section after running the test:

Request:

```
{
"body": {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "credit_card",
        "funding_instruments": [
            {
                "credit_card": {
                    "first_name": "John Doe",
                    "expire_month": 10,
                    "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx6370",
                    "cvv2": "***",
                    "expire_year": 2020,
                    "type": "visa"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "13.80"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"header": {
    "content-length": "461",
    "paypal-request-id": "c01e88d8-a784-42a6-adc8-4412e51d041b",
    "x-pp-silover": "name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D1748763222",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "accept": "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q\\u003d.2, */*; q\\u003d.2",
    "client-auth": "No cert",
    "host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
    "user-agent": "PayPalSDK/PayPal-Java-SDK 1.2.8 (lang\\u003dJava;v\\u003d1.7.0_45;bit\\u003d64;os\\u003dWindows_8 6.2)",
    "authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxG5ws",
    "x-pp-corrid": "64ec69a84149",
    "pp_remote_addr": "106.51.131.226",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-pp-slingshot-targetapp": "platformapiserv"
},
"additional_properties": {},
"method": "POST"
```

}

Response:

```
{
"status": 400,
"duration_time": 1523,
"body": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR",
    "name": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
    "debug_id": "64ec69a84149"
},
"additional_properties": {},
"header": {
    "Content-Length": "184",
    "Content-Language": "*",
    "CORRELATION-ID": "64ec69a84149",
    "Date": "Wed, 23 Sep 2015 05:45:13 GMT",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Paypal-Debug-Id": "64ec69a84149",
    "PROXY_SERVER_INFO": "host\\u003dslcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId\\u003d355",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

}

please help me

Comment: Show some code pal, how can we suggest whats wrong without any code.

Comment: According to the link you've provided, it's an internal error - that is, internal to PayPal. They're not telling you what went wrong and why. Their only suggestion is to try it again later. So what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: added a test that used to run, let me know if more detail required

Comment: Logged a ticket on paypal developer site for this issue, got reply from them saying that hey had a known issue at our server and this has caused the http response 500. This issue was fixed now and everything seems to be working as expected

Comment: Thanks for your help